# Unable to create users on free edition of Cloud Identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I recently bought a new domain and wanted to start using GCP with my new domain using the free edition of Cloud Identity.

I managed to signup but the DNS verification gives server error on this page:

https://admin.google.com/setup/u/0/identity/gcp.

Then I used this:

https://admin.google.com/u/0/ac/signup/setup/v2/explore,

after adding the TXT entry in my DNS it showed verified.
After this when I try to create a user it goes back to

https://admin.google.com/setup/u/0/identity/gcp

which still shows domain not verified. Has someone seen this bug before?

Comment: This a could-provider specific problem.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are receiving? Did you follow this exact [document](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/setup) to set up the Cloud Identity? Also, please look at the common sign up [issues](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7332529) and [verify the domain](https://cloud.google.com/identity/docs/verify-domain). Hope it helps!